# changing the json deserialized type to an array

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I have scaffolded a web api controller with Entity Framework.
Whenever i POST a single json object, that works. But i keep on getting errors whenever the JSON object is included in an array [{},{},].
The error below through Postman:

```
"Message": "The request is invalid.",
"ModelState": {
    "incidence": [
        "Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'TSCAPP.Models.Incidence' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) to deserialize correctly.\r\nTo fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.\r\nPath '', line 1, position 1."
```

POST Controller:

```
    [ResponseType(typeof(Incidence))]
    public IHttpActionResult PostIncidence(Incidence incidence)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        db.Incidences.Add(incidence);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = incidence.RegistrationID }, incidence);
    }
```

Incidence Model

```
public class Incidence
{
    [Key]
    public int RegistrationID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MinLength(6)]
    public string TSCNO { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    public string CellPhone { get; set; }
    public string IncidenceType { get; set; }
    public string RequestType { get; set; }
    public string County { get; set; }
    public string ExactLocation { get; set; }
    public string Request { get; set; }
    public int? RoleID { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string FeedBack { get; set; }
}
```

JSON file posted

[
   {
        "RegistrationID": 1,
        "Name": "Evan",
        "TSCNO": "662621",
        "EmailAddress": "evan@mail.com",
        "CellPhone": "254722543778",
        "IncidenceType": null,
        "RequestType": null,
        "County": "West Pokot",
        "ExactLocation": "Kapenguria",
        "Request": " Nil",
        "RoleID": 2,
        "FeedBack": ""
    },
    {
        "RegistrationID": 2,
        "Name": "John",
        "TSCNO": "607921",
        "EmailAddress": "john@mail.com",
        "CellPhone": "254700172168",
        "IncidenceType": null,
        "RequestType": null,
        "County": "Kwale",
        "ExactLocation": "Mkongani",
        "Request": "dependats",
        "RoleID": 2,
        "FeedBack": ""
    }
]

Comment: Show us `Incidence` class and json which you posted

Answer (score 2):

Model binding cannot magically understand if you are expecting one or many elements. The format is incompatible. You have to define another endpoint if you want to bind an array.

```
public IHttpActionResult PostIncidences(Incidence[] incidences)
```

Comment: kindly elaborate further.

Comment: In JSON, a single object ({}) and an array of objects([{},{}]) are defined with different syntax. You have to tell ASP.NET which one you are expecting and they cannot be used interchangeably. So you have to have separate action methods for each: one that expects a single object and one that expects an array.

Answer (score 1):

@ufuk-hacıoğulları  I have changed it to this and is working as expected

```
    [ResponseType(typeof(Incidence))]
    public IHttpActionResult PostIncidence([FromBody] List<Incidence> incidence)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        foreach (var orp in incidence)
        {
            db.Incidences.Add(orp);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        return Ok(incidence);
    }
```